# Yfinance: downloading multiple parameters (beta, mkt cap, etc.) for multiple stocks at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, finance, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I am trying to use Yfinance to download into a single pandas dataframe some info such as industry, beta and market cap (**columns**) for a number of S&P stocks (**rows**). In the simplified example below it's the industry and beta of 3 stocks.

1. How can I automate the code so that I don't have to use info.get() each time ? I plan on downloading about 10 different parameters besides the industry and beta...
2. What is the best way to turn the current output (a list) into the pandas dataframe I outlined above? Thanks!

---

```
import yfinance as yf
stocks = ['JNJ', 'MSFT','GS']
df=[]
    for stock in stocks: 
    info = yf.Ticker(stock).info
    industry = info.get('industry')
    beta = info.get('beta')
    df.extend((stock,industry,beta))
print(df)
```

===== OUTPUT ====

`['JNJ', 'Drug Manufacturers—General', 0.711267, 'MSFT', 'Software—Infrastructure', 0.812567, 'GS', 'Capital Markets', 1.484832]`

Answer (score 3):

The return value of '.info' is in dict format, so you can extract it once you get it. Put it in a data frame and list it.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

stocks = ['JNJ', 'MSFT','GS']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for stock in stocks: 
    info = yf.Ticker(stock).info
    industry = info['industry']
    beta = info['beta']
    marketcap = info['marketCap']    
    df = df.append({'Stock':stock,'Industry':industry,'Beta':beta,'marketcap':marketcap}, ignore_index=True)
    
print(df)
       Beta                    Industry Stock     marketcap
0  0.711267  Drug Manufacturers—General   JNJ  4.103370e+11
1  0.812567     Software—Infrastructure  MSFT  1.746778e+12
2  1.484832             Capital Markets    GS  1.132026e+11
```

Specify the first column

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Stock','Industry','Beta','Marketcap'])
```

Finally, change the column order.

```
df.columns = ['Stock','Industry','Beta','Marketcap']
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer and give it 1+, thanks!

Comment: Thank you! 2 questions: How can I make sure that the columns of df are in the order I want? I'd like to have the stock ticker in the first column.*** Secondly, how can I automate the info['xyz'] function, so that I dont  have to write it over and over for  industry, market cap, beta and so on? I tried and get the error "unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: Since it was added to an empty data frame, the column order is alphabetical, so you can either specify the columns in the first data frame or change the column order to the desired one at the end. You can either specify the columns in the first data frame or change the order to the desired one at the end.